# How can I attach to an existing TFS project in VS 2003 / XP Mode?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2003, xp-mode, msscci, sln-file

In order to bring over some files from source control into my XP-Moded instance of Visual Studio 2003, I was able to bring over *some* of the files from source control by selecting (in Visual Studio 2003) File > Source Control > Open From Source Control...attaching to the TFS server, navigating to and then selecting the desired project.

However, that operation did not bring over the *.sln file, so I am not able to open that project (the *.cs file is there, but not its "host" sln file).

I then tried to attach / bring over the missing files via File > Source Control > Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider

On doing this, I am warmly (I think) welcomed by the "Visual Studio Conversion Wizard" but, although it seems to work, it doesn't bring over the *.sln file either, purportedly because the *.sln file was created with a different version of VS (so it seemingly gleefully tells me) -- no doubt it's talking about the VS 2003 / VS 2010 (shell) mismatch...?

So the local folder where I am attempting to put the files is missing *.sln:

[image]

The *.sln file does exist in the TFS server area - when I select File > Source Control > Open from Source Control > Connect to a Team Foundation Server > Expand the folder dialog > Navigate to the project I want, this is what I see:

[image]

...but highlighting, and even 2-clicking, HUtilCE.sln does not transfer it to the Filename combo box - I have to manually type it into there, but then when I mash the "Open" button I get, "Unspecified error."

So which hoops, and in which order, must I jump through to attach to this project; and what grade of fire retardant should I spray on my tail before taking that fiery plunge?

Comment: Which version of TFS?

Comment: I don't know - how do I determine that?

Comment: Ask the Admin is the easiest way.

Comment: That would be like asking Santa Claus (there's no such animal).

Comment: If you have access, log on to the TFS server and run up the TFS administration console. The splash screen should give you the info. Either way I've found that the MSSCCI provider is poor. I've had much more success installing Team Explorer 2010 and using that as a source control window whilst using VS 2003 just for writing the code. If you're using TFS 2010 then that's all you need to do. If you're using a more recent version of TFS then you'll need to update Team Explorer 2010 with a compatibility update. I don't think you can install more recent versions of Team Explorer on Win XP.

Comment: I don't know how to do that; I get to TFS indirectly through the menu items in Visual Studio and don't know how to access the TFS server directly.

Comment: can you open the sln file in a text editor within windows explorer? that should at least tell you which version of visual studio the solution was created with?

Comment: It was created with Visual Studio 2003. The only thing the .sln file says about it is: Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 8.00